# How do I view macro code without running them?

Tags: vba, excel

I work for a company which has a mechanism in place to control and block messages with certains extensions, like .doc, .xls, xlsx, xlsm et cetera.

We receive a lot of requests to approve those messages because they are relevant to our customers, but before we do that, we check the attached files for code in VBA, but when I open them I get the message "PROTECTED VIEW Files from the internet can contain viruses" and if I proceed to open the VBA editor (ALT + F11), the code isn't there.

There is nothing. No Sheet, no ThisWorkBook, nothing. Everything is greyed out. So how do I view the code, without running potential malicious macro code AND stay in protected mode.

When I enable all macro's without notification or hit "Enable editing", it works, but that is not something I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can't see the code in Protected View (unless there is a trick which someone will share.)

But for the part  *So how do I view the code, without running potential malicious macro code* .... here is the solution:

Using **Application.AutomationSecurity** you can build/create a basic macro, which will allow you to open all the recieved files in macro disabled mode.

You can then manually read the code. (Hope you are not trying to build a code scanner!)

Here is example to start with from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837822.aspx)

```
 Sub Security()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim secAutomation As MsoAutomationSecurity

    secAutomation = Application.AutomationSecurity

    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    '/ Just an example workbook.
    strFile = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\fail-test.xlsm"

    Workbooks.Open strFile

    '/ once the workbook is launced, yoou applicationsetting is restored.
    Application.AutomationSecurity = secAutomation

End Sub
```